# Add headings to the code ? First heading job and second heading salary

Tags: python, excel, csv

Learning python

```
    import re
    x="job"
    filename="jobprofiles.txt"
    job=[]
    salary=[]
    with open(filename, "rt") as in_file:
              for line in in_file:
               line = line.translate(none, "!")
                        if x in line:
                            job.append((line[line.find(x)+len(x):]].strip())
    import re
    x="salary"
    filename="jobprofiles.txt"
    with open(filename, "rt") as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
           line = line.translate(none, "!")
           if x in line:
                  salary.append((line[line.find(x)+len(x):]].strip())
   for i in range(1,len(job)):
   print job[i-1]+ ","+ir[i-1]
```

My sample output:

ACCOUNTANT,32000
VET,42000
FINANCE,40000
TEACHER,25000
BUSINESS,32000
DOCTOR,45000

How would I add headings 
For example 
JOB                   SALARY
ACCOUNTANT,   32000
VET,                    42000
FINANCE,           40000
TEACHER,          25000
BUSINESS,         32000
DOCTOR,45000

Comment: can you give sample data of jobprofiles.txt and expexted output for csv file

Comment: as Jay Shankar Gupta said, it would be good to have an example file.

Comment: Does it need to be read by a user/other program, or just another Python script you write?

Comment: Have a look at the `csv` library or `pandas` library.